# Scraping data from a table from a specific title value and filter specific lines (Google App Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping, cheerio

Documentation for `CherrioGS`:
https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs

The idea is to collect only data from the table with the name `Argentinos Jrs` and that lines with the value `Away on International duty` in the `info` column are not saved.

Note: I really need to specify according to the value `Argentinos Jrs` and remove `Away on International duty`, because the position of this table is not fixed and the values in lines too.

The expected result in this example I'm looking for is this:

```
Carlos Quintana      Mid August
Jonathan Sandoval    Early August
```

The website link is this:
https://www.sportsgambler.com/injuries/football/argentina-superliga/

I will leave the current image of the site because if the data changes, the idea of my example is registered:
[image]

The code I try:

```
function PaginaDoJogo() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Dados Importados');
    var url = 'https://www.sportsgambler.com/injuries/football/argentina-superliga/';

    const contentText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    const $ = Cheerio.load(contentText);

    $('div:contains("Argentinos Jrs") > div > div.inj-container:not(contains("Away on International duty")) > span.inj-player')
        .each((index, element) => {
            sheet.getRange(index + 2, 1).setValue($(element).text());
        });

    $('div:contains("Argentinos Jrs") > div > div.inj-container:not(contains("Away on International duty")) > span.inj-return.h-sm')
        .each((index, element) => {
            sheet.getRange(index + 2, 2).setValue($(element).text());
        });
}
```

Comment: does your jquery expression not work?

Comment: Good night, thanks in advance for your help! Correct @Alex , it's not working.

Comment: try to remove parts of the jquery to find where the problem is.  Start from the back, and when you get the right answer, you found an incorrect part

Comment: I'm still learning how to work with selector elements to use with Cheerio, the question really is why I need help to create an option that works because my use ```not(contains())``` not work.

Comment: honestly you don't need to use jquery in node.  You can use something like jsdom and use the web style querySelector to get what you need. It will be way easier than what you are doing.  It's painful to read your jquery queries.

Comment: I think there is no way to use Node inside the Google App Script (I had put it in the question tags, but now I've also added it to the title for easier viewing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function PaginaDoJogo() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Dados Importados');
  const url = 'https://www.sportsgambler.com/injuries/football/argentina-superliga/';
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const content = response.getContentText();
  const match = content.match(/Argentinos Jrs[\s\S]+?<!--Livestream call to action-->/);
  const regExp = /<div[\s\S]+?<span class="inj-player">(.+?)<\/span>[\s\S]+?<span class="inj-info">(.+?)<\/span>[\s\S]+?<span class="inj-return h-sm">(.+?)<\/span>[\s\S]+?<\/div>/g;
  const values = [];
  while ((r = regExp.exec(match[0])) !== null) {
    // console.log(r[1], r[2], r[3]);
    if (r[1] !== 'Name' && r[2] !== 'Away on International duty') {
      values.push([r[1], r[3]]);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, 2).setValues(values);
}
```