# Looping only delivers the last collected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to use `index+row` to put the values in the rows of my spreadsheet, in theory there are two collected values and I would like one to appear on `row 10` and the other on `row 11`, but that's not happening, how should I go about solving this problem?

**Note:** The result of this code puts the last value collected in `row 10`, when I would like the first value to be placed in `row 10` and the second in `row 11`.

**Note 2:** As I understand it, the first index is `0`, so the sum of rows becomes `0+10` and the second index is `1`, so the sum of rows becomes `1+10`.

```
function MenuDoPlantelTimeA() {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Dados Importados Time A');
    const url = 'https://www.soccer-rating.com/Juventus-Torino/1593/';

    const contentText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    const $ = Cheerio.load(contentText);
  
    let elements = $('a')

    elements.each((index, value) => {
        let href = $(value).attr('href')
        if (href === 'javascript:showSquad()') {
        sheet.getRange(index+10, 1).setValue($(value).text().trim())
        }
    })
}
```

Values Colected:

```
Udinese Calcio
Juventus Torino
```

Comment: When you say `but that's not happening` then what is happening? do they appear somewhere else or not at all?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i add in my question the ```Note```about result of my actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not querying correctly.

```js
    let elements = $('a[href="javascript:showSquad()"]')

    elements.each((index, value) => {
      sheet.getRange(index+10, 1).setValue($(value).text().trim())
    })
```

Comment: By the way, please update [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68840508/scraping-data-from-a-table-from-a-specific-title-value-and-filter-specific-lines)

Comment: Sorry, I usually update when I take the test, but I forgot!